# How to update cell background after delete

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom backgrounds (one for first rows, other for middle rows and other for last rows). When I delete a row of the tableView (swipe to delete), if I delete the first row, the new first row that was a middle row before that, stills remains with the middle background.

I tried to reloadData and it works but it kills the nice fade animation when deleting.

How can I update the style without killing the smooth animation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` (Create an array with the index path of the table row(s) to be updated). When inbetween a call to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` you can use this to create a smooth animation. (all methods to be called on UITableView)

Note that these functions do have an understanding of "before" and "after" the update and can check if section and row counts are appropriate (especially important when also inserting and deleting between beginUpdates and endUpdates.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is rerun through your logic, depending on how many cells you have, and loop though how many rows you have

then you can get that cell via:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(int)someRow inSection:(int)whateverSection];
```

and then reset the background color on it